# Django South: Auto schemamigration didn't work for adding ManyToMany

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-south, schema-migration

I am pretty new to south. I am working off of a friends project, and he seems to already have done some migrations.

I have a model and I am trying to to add an additional ManyToMany field to it. This is the class with `owned_geofences` being the field I am trying to add:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    owned_beacons = models.ManyToManyField(
       Beacon,
       blank=True,
       null=True,
       related_name='owned_beacons'
       )

    #trying to add this one below
    owned_goefences = models.ManyToManyField(
        Geofence,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='owned_geofences'
        )
```

The app is named 'profile'. First I did this:

```
$ sudo python manage.py schemamigration profile --auto
 + Added M2M table for owned_goefences on profile.UserProfile
Created 0007_auto.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate profile
```

Cool it seems to have worked. Then I did this:

```
$ python manage.py migrate profile
Running migrations for profile:
 - Migrating forwards to 0007_auto.
 > profile:0007_auto
 - Loading initial data for profile.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Okay. Now *It* should be working right?

Well, it does seem to have worked. I ran some tests and..

```
>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=1)
<User: nick>
# just to test if user is working properly
>>> user.get_profile().owned_beacons
<django.db.models.fields.related.ManyRelatedManager object at 0x1104e7d50>
# this is the one that isn't working
>>> user.get_profile().owned_geofences
AttributeError: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'owned_geofences'
```

On top of that, out of curiousity I ran:

```
$ python manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.admindocs
 > south

Not synced (use migrations):
 - pp.apps.careers
 - pp.apps.contact
 - pp.apps.geofencemanager
 - pp.apps.locationmanager
 - pp.apps.messagemanager
 - django_extensions
 - pp.profile
 - pp.apps.beaconmanager
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)
```

Why aren't these synced? I thought I was messing up something so I took the advice above and ran:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Running migrations for careers:
- Nothing to migrate.
#etc for all of them
```

Can someone please shed some light on what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you run `syncdb`, apps that already have migrations will be ignored, that's why they are not synced.

Second of all problem is not in south, it did the migration fine, you should check your database, just to make sure if it created the through table ('appname_userprofile_geofence', or something like that), I am sure it did since it said so: `> profile:0007_auto`, also it would haven given you a `DatabaseError` if migration wasn't done, not `AttributeError`.

Moreover everything seems to be fine, make sure you reload the shell, so it has updated version of `UserProfile` model.